# Response from generalized linear model is opposite what is expected?

Tags: r

I'm attempting to use n-fold cross-validation to estimate the mcr of a logistic regression classifier, however, the results I am getting are opposite what I'm expecting, and I'm not sure why?

Here is my complete R code:

```
library(ALL); data(ALL); library(caret)
IsB <- ALL$BT
levels(IsB) <- c(rep(TRUE, 5), rep(FALSE, 5))

ALL.names <- ALL[c('39317_at', '38018_g_at'),]
expr.data <- t(exprs(ALL.names))
data.lgr <- data.frame(IsB, expr.data)
n <- dim(data.lgr)[1]
index <- 1:n
K <- n
flds <- createFolds(index, k = K)
mcr.cv.raw <- rep(NA, K)
for (i in 1:K) {
  testID <- flds[[i]]
  data.tr <- data.lgr[-testID,]
  data.test <- data.lgr[testID,]
  reg.lgr <- glm(IsB ~ ., data = data.tr, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
  pred.prob <- predict(reg.lgr, newdata = data.test, type="response")
  pred.B <- (pred.prob > 0.5)
  mcr.cv.raw[i] <- sum(pred.B != data.test$IsB) / length(pred.B)
}
mcr.cv <- mean(mcr.cv.raw)
mcr.cv
```

Running this code will output 0.90625, however, this is almost the exact opposite of what I would expect.  I think that the problem is coming from the values of pred.prob generated in the for loop.  Logically, I am assuming that the probabilities produced are the probability that the sample in data.test would be classified as true, but when looking at all of the values generated for pred.b vs all of the value in IsB, you can see that they are all opposite what one would expect:

pred.b:

```
  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [11] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [21] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [31] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [41] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [51] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [61] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [71] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 [81] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [91] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[101]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[111] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[121]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

IsB:

```
  [1] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
 [11] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
 [21] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
 [31] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
 [41] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
 [51] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
 [61] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
 [71] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
 [81] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
 [91] TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[101] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[111] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[121] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Any help with where my logic or code is failing is appreciated!

Comment: Check your factor labels. The function takes the factors with `0` and  `1`  according to the alphabetic order. So, your problem could be the order of the factors.

Comment: I think you are right.  I changed the TRUEs and FALSEs to 1s and 0s, and it worked correctly.  I wasn't able to just do as.numeric(IsB) as that produced a list of 1s and 2s.  I needed to do (2 - as.numeric(IsB)), do you know why that would be?

Comment: By default, a factor defines its levels as `1, 2, 3, . . .` , so if you want `0` and `1`, you should use some changes as the one you propose.